# Gui JList ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist

hey all goodevening i have a problem about my second button named "Submit" because i cant transfer all information i entered to my null JList in the frame here is my code so far my problem is if i clicked submit my all information will appear in my Message area in frame it needs to be list. thanks

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class vin extends JFrame
{
        JLabel lab = new JLabel("Enter Your Name :");
        JLabel lab2 = new JLabel("Enter Your Birthday :");
        JLabel lab3 = new JLabel("Enter Your Age:");
        JLabel lab4 = new JLabel("Enter Your HomeTown:");
        JLabel lab5 = new JLabel("Choose Your Department:");
        JButton b1 = new JButton("Exit");
        JTextField t1 = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField t2 = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField t3 = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField t4 = new JTextField(15);
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Submit");
        JButton b3 = new JButton("Clear");
         JLabel lab6 = new JLabel("Message :");
        JList list = new JList();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel brief;

    public vin()
    {

        setLocation(500,280);
        panel.setLayout(null);


        lab.setBounds(10,10,150,20);
        t1.setBounds(130,10,150,20);
        lab5.setBounds(10,40,150,20);
        lab2.setBounds(10,140,150,20);
        t2.setBounds(130,140,150,20);
        lab3.setBounds(10,170,150,20);
        t3.setBounds(110,170,150,20);
        lab4.setBounds(10,200,150,20);
        t4.setBounds(150,200,150,20);
        lab6.setBounds(10,240,150,20);
        list.setBounds(50,270,150,20);
        list.setSize(250,150);
        b1.setBounds(250,470,150,20);
        b2.setBounds(60,470,150,20);
        b3.setBounds(160,470,150,20);
        b1.setSize(60,30);
        b2.setSize(75,30);
        b3.setSize(65,30);


        panel.add(lab);
        panel.add(t1);
        panel.add(lab5);
        panel.add(lab2);
        panel.add(t2);
        panel.add(t3);
        panel.add(t4);
        panel.add(lab4);
        panel.add(lab3);
        panel.add(lab6);
        panel.add(b1);
        panel.add(b2);
        panel.add(b3);
        panel.add(list);

        brief = new JLabel("Goodmorning "+t1+" Today is "+t2+" its your birthday You are now"+t3+" of age You are From"+t4);
        getContentPane().add(panel);


        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
           {
               Object source = a.getSource();

               if(source == b1)
               {
                   System.exit(0);
               }
           }
        });

        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
            {
                Object source = a.getSource();

                if(source == b2)
                {
                   list = new JList();
                }  
            }
        });
        b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
           {
               Object source = a.getSource();

               if(source == b3)
               {
                   t1.setText("");
                   t2.setText("");
                   t3.setText("");
                   t4.setText("");
               }
           }
        });
    }       

    public static void main(String args [])
    {
        vin w = new vin();

        w.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        w.setSize(400,600);
        w.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not really clear what you are asking.You want to have listener on b2 that if you click will initialize list and then? thats it?

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem, why you you make inside `actionListener`  `list = new JList()` ?

Comment: yes sir if i click b2 it will appear in my message the bottom white in my frame sir . it will appear the all information like name,age,etc

Comment: @nachokk because i need to call out my all information to my JList in my frame .

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Instead try and explain what exactly your code is to achieve, how your program is supposed to work, and what it currently does wrong (or doesnt do)

Comment: Now i think i understand a little ..You have text fields that take informations and you wnat to take that info on submit click and put it into list?

Comment: yes @TomasBisciak sir

Comment: sir @TomasBisciak is right thats my point sir .

Comment: @peeskillet i need to submit my all information in my JList .

Comment: Please refrain from asking [**Duplicate Questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21779912/2587435)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so from what i understand this gonna take informations from Fields and put them into LIST that you have there

b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
        {
            DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
            listModel.addElement(t1.getText());
            listModel.addElement(t2.getText());
            listModel.addElement(t3.getText());
            listModel.addElement(t4.getText());
            list.setModel(listModel);


        }
    });
```

this i made simple for you so you can see what im doing i woud put txtfield to array so its easyer bud this will work for you just fine :)

You can do it with arrays and for loops so you can get rid off the listmodel.add .... etc each time and when you will want to sore all that info user put previously use for example arraylist.Im not sure how you expect your program to run next time when you post quesiton please point out exact problem and how do you expect program to work in detail.also post just relevant code not all of it.

Comment: can i add some String in the t1.getText()); ? like ("blabla"+t1.getText()); ?

Comment: ofcourse you can.:) TRY and you will see.It behaves exactly like a string when you are returning it